# Print new line in a file using Python

Tags: python, string, file, newline

I used the following code. The genetarated_rtl.v file contains the text with \n character. It doesn't come up with a new line. But the new line character is printed.

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
    filePath = '/delsoft/lakmald2/Auto/2-GEN/1-Test/for_simple1.rgt'

    rtl = open ('generated_rtl.v', 'wb')
    f = open(filePath,'r')

    def insertSTR(conData):
        printToFile(conData)
        sys.stdout.write(conData)

    def printToFile(data):
        rtl.write(data)

    def insertUSR(conData):
        currentInput = input (conData)
        printToFile(str(currentInput))  

    for line in f:
        conTyp,conData = line.split("::")
        #print conTyp+" is "+conData

        if conTyp == 'STR':
            insertSTR(conData)
        elif conTyp == 'USR':
            insertUSR(conData);

        else :
            print 'ERROR'       

    rtl.close()
```

When I give the for_simple1.rgt file as below, \n gets printed. I don't want that. What I want is a new line.

```
STR::for (int i=0;i<
USR::
STR::;i++)\nbegin\n
CON::
STR::end\n
END::
```

Comment: And what exactly would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a literal backslash followed by a literal 'n' to a newline, you can decode the string using the `string_escape` encoding:

```
>>> s = r'what\nwhat\nwhat'
>>> print(s)
what\nwhat\nwhat
>>> print(s.decode('string_escape'))
what
what
what
>>>
```

So your function would be:

```
def printToFile(data):
    rtl.write(data.decode('string_escape'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. What I want is to remove the printed \n character and add a new line.

Comment: @user3134019 Okay, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) function:

```
def printToFile(data):
    new_data = data.replace('\\n', '\n')
    rtl.write(new_data)
```